# I have got stucked in grub2 while installing ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2

I have tried to install ubuntu 18.04 the whole night.I frequently stucked in grub2 installation.I installed boot repair to get what the problem i am facing.This is the URL given by boot repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wc6qvV37F3/ .Please give how can i recover this problem.What can i do?

Comment: What brand/model system? You have a very old grub legacy in gpt's protective MBR, but have gpt partitioning and an ESP - efi system partition. And you have booted installer in UEFI mode, so can reinstall grub & kernel using Boot-Repair's advanced mode. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Your UEFI boot entry also shows "unknown" for the entry that  normally would say ubuntu. Is this an Acer as with Acer you have to set "trust" in UEFI. Many also need UEFI updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delay. My system is acer aspire es 15 .While I was installing  grub package shows some here. What Can I do?

Comment: You have to set "trust" from within UEFI. You probably have to update UEFI from Acer, also. See link above on install steps. Trust settings in step 35.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Kindly boot your system again with bootable usb/dvd device in order to reinstall or repair grub live from bootable device. Don't worry, in this process you won't loss any data.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Let me check. I reinstallled grub 2 package. But the error is still remaining